# Why were Wolverine’s metal blades shaped differently than his bone claws?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, marvel, x-men-origins-wolverine

In *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*, he had ugly bones coming out of his hands. Assuming adamantium replaced his skeleton, the adamantium should have taken their shape, instead of being nicely-shaped blades.

So was there a different explanation for Wolverine's claws or is it just so?

Comment: Well like most animals he would have sharpened the bone claws by use. So before he got them coated with Adamantium they would be excellent blades. After that he wouldn't need to sharpen them again as they would never dull.

Comment: To me they appeared to be roundish and pointy when bones, when claws they have a cutting edge, slanted point. Why is this?

Comment: @JoshSchwarzzeskywalker: An example of the bony claws: http://psychoandy.wikia.com/wiki/Bone_Claw_Wolverine

Comment: “assuming adamantium replaced his skeleton” — it didn’t.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've not seen Origins, but this has been inconsistently displayed through the comics.

I believe that, in the most recent canon I've read, Wolverine's claws are bone, laced with Adamantium like the rest of his skeleton.  This makes sense (in the comic book usage of the term, at least) because if the claws weren't part of his original skeleton he wouldn't have had the musculature in place to extend or retract them.

As for the appearance in Origins, I can't answer why they would appear rough.  I would expect that any claws would be similar to a cat's - smooth on the sides.  They wouldn't be curved, of course, as they have to be stored in the forearm while retracted.  It's likely that the Adamantium bonding would fill and smooth out any irregularities as it plated the bones, which could account for the visual difference you point out.

Comment: They probably took from Wolverine's claws in the comics after Magneto ripped the adamantium from his bones in X-Men #25; [for almost five years after, his claws had a rough appearance](http://goodcomics.comicbookresources.com/2007/03/29/comic-book-urban-legends-revealed-96/) (see the bottom for an image, or do a [Google image search for "wolverine bone claws"](https://www.google.com/search?q=wolverine+bone+claws&hl=en&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=JUb9TvKUEIT30gHr8YyyAg&ved=0CDMQsAQ&biw=1920&bih=1075))

Answer (score 14):

The Adamantium didn't replace his bones, they just covered them. So, technically, they could have taken any shape the scientists wanted.

As for the shape of the claws, it is a well known fact in the X-Men universe that most mutant abilities activate only during a heightened emotional state during puberty (with some exceptions of mutations at birth). So, I propose that Wolverine's claws didn't appear until during puberty, which could explain why his body hadn't smoothed out the claws yet.

Comment: Also note that the claws were the only exposed bones (except the teeth). Perhaps this is why the adamantium covered the claws externally. Why he doesn't have adamantium teeth, I don't know.

Comment: I don't mean to contradict an answer, but if we are only talking X-Men: Origins then Wolverine had his claws come out before he hit puberty as seen in the introduction of the film.

Comment: I think What he's asking is, Why are they claw shaped before the adamantium and blade shaped after the adamantium? I'm curious about this too. If his bones were coated with the metal, then he shouldn't have blades coming out. He should just have metal claws much like Yuriko in X2.

Comment: As I recall it, his mother had 3 scar lines on her back and when the other party tries to ask about it - the whole scene is silenced. I assumed it to be a hungry angry baby wanting something (food).

Comment: Claws upon hitting puberty?  Yikes!