# What's with the shape of Wolverine's claws in the future?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, x-men-days-of-future-past, marvel

There is already this question:
[Does Wolverine still get his adamantium skeleton after Days of Future Past?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/57250/does-wolverine-still-get-his-adamantium-skeleton-after-days-of-future-past)

To me, the claws in the future were squared off at the end and not pointy, more like a bevel end chisel.

What did I see and what is the reason for this?

Comment: related, not dupe: [How did Wolverine get his sharp claws?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5388/how-did-wolverine-get-his-sharp-claws) - it talks about why the claws have honed edges instead of following the bone shape

Comment: [promo image of future-wolverine](http://static.squarespace.com/static/51b3dc8ee4b051b96ceb10de/t/52eadd6be4b02e3a7e2b9933/1391123822478/)

Comment: @phantom42:   This is not what I remember from the film.   Am I mis-remembering?

Comment: Maybe? Do you mean that you recall him having claws without sharpened tips of any sort? I didn't exactly study his future-claws during the movie, but I didn't notice them being significantly different from his normal adamantium ones.

Comment: The claws in that image definitely don't match the film.

Comment: @phantom42, Keen:   Yes.   Much more like a bevel edge chisel http://www.faithfulltools.com/images/extralarge/FAIWCR6.jpg   ... but without the raised flat part parallel to the largest surface.   I.e. the end portion is a triangle, not a trapezoid.   At least that's my memory.

Comment: Hm. I'll try digging a bit more later today.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: I don’t recall Wolverine having squared-off claws in *Future Past*. He cuts Kitty Pryde with them pretty well.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: Squared off doesn't not sharp.   I don't want anyone swinging that chisel at me.   Especially if it's Jackman and it's adamantium.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: sure. But I still think you didn’t see what you think you saw.

Comment: FWIW, [the official poster](https://wegeekgirls.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/x-men_days-of-future-past_mystique-and-wolverine.jpg) also has the normal claws.

Comment: Found [a quote from Singer](http://www.empireonline.com/news/story.asp?NID=39969) implying that Magneto fixed the claws, though I don't recall that actually being mentioned in the movie. If Magneto is involved, any shape is possible.

Comment: Well, they are not like I thought, but there's still something weird about the shape.  Around time 1:06:10.  Or maybe it's just the angle.

Comment: I dont remember him showing his claws in the new future. Only in the old future where he stabs Kitty. And those were definitely adamantium sharp edged claws. In the past wolverine his bone claws were also shaped (ex. http://i.stack.imgur.com/8NPrL.jpg) not blunt.

Comment: I found [this video clip](http://x-mendaysoffuturepast.tumblr.com/post/85522740616/x-men-days-of-future-past-wolverine-hologram). In the 3/4 angle view, I could see the claws as being interpreted as having a blunt tip, but the other angles show that they're sharp.

Comment: There is also this one http://i.imgur.com/CRkynNN.png, the claws have a much darker contrast one them the usual silvery color in other X-Men movies.

Comment: The last movie was playing in the year 1973 that is 2 year before he meet Stryker. Because the mutants saved the president Stryker never became General. No Stryker = no adamantium skeleton.

Comment: I've voted to close. Unless you can provide some evidence of Wolverine's claws with blunted ends, I think it's likely that you're simply misremembering.

Comment: @Valorum:   Per your comment, I finally have the evidence of why I thought this.  It is also an answer.   Please reopen.    This deserves an answer, which I can't do, in the closed state.

Comment: @Valorum:   ([hint](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7vao8.jpg))

Comment: @ThePopMachine - They don't look blunt to me.

Comment: @Valorum -- because of the high contrast and and quick edit, I only saw the portion to the left.   I didn't see the three horizontal lines on the right or any of the parts in shadow.    Basically cover the righthand 1/3 of the screen and that's what I saw in the theatre.   Or maybe blur your eyes a little so much of the length merges into the background.

Comment: Mandela effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a screen capture of the offending appearance:

[image]

Actually, what I saw is due to the quick edit and the high contrast in the scene with an unfortunate shadow which appeared to hide much of the length and blend it into the background.

The three horizontal lines on the right of the image and most of the blade could not be readily noticed.   (Just turn down your monitor's brightness or blur your eyes to see the effect.)

No in- or out-of-universe explanation is necessary besides lighting and human perception.